# PHP Regexp with dash and ampersand doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, ampersand

here is a string:

```
$test =  '<a id="test">One &amp; -Two&nbsp;-&nbsp;Three</a>';
```

And I would like to catch those two strings into 2 differents variable like:

```
$string1 = 'One &amp; -Two';
```

and

```
$string2 = 'Three';
```

So I've use a preg_match_all but I have a problem with the regexp:

```
preg_match_all('#([-;\w\ \.\/\'\d\(\)\&]+)+&nbsp;-&nbsp;([\w+\ \.\-]+)+#', $test, $matches);
```

Could someone explain me why it doesn't work..? I don't see which 'rule' I don't respect here..

Comment: Are you trying to get value from html element using regex, If so, please use dom or simple html dom

Comment: be aware that `([-;\w\ \.\/\'\d\(\)\&]+)+` initiates catastrophic backtracking, if the matching fails

Comment: You also have **lots** of unnecessary backslashes, making the thing very hard to read...

Comment: [Look here](https://ideone.com/Tce36u), no need for a regex. It is actually the first `)+` that causes the catastrophic backtracking issue. The last one is OK, though totally redudant (the engine knows how to deal with just `/(a+)+/`).

Comment: You could use https://regex101.com/ as a first step to debug regex and if you do you'll read something like : `Catastrophic backtracking has been detected` which is useful information

Comment: I know that it's the first group `[-;\w\ \.\/\'\d\(\)\&]+` that cause the catastrophic backtracking, the problem is that I need all characters that are inside of it because it's a preg_match_all and this string is not the only one that I need to catch. I also already use regexp101 to debug, but I still don't find a way to catch this string like I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `+` after `)` (`([-;\w\ \.\/\'\d\(\)\&]+)+`) [causes the catastrophic backtracking issue](https://regex101.com/r/J4ak3p/1) (see [more on this here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)) as this is the case of a `(a+)+` type of pattern that is not the ending subpattern. Removing that `+` already [solves the issue](https://regex101.com/r/NnW5IT/1).

The last subpattern has the very same issue, but is not causing trouble due to internal PCRE optimizations.

Also, I think you do not need any regex here, use `explode` and `strip_tags`:

```
$test =  '<a id="test">One &amp; -Two&nbsp;-&nbsp;Three</a>';
$res = explode("&nbsp;-&nbsp;", strip_tags($test));
echo $res[0]. "\n" . $res[1];
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Tce36u)